# make a dropped div, droppable again

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to make an editor of a sort were you choose your layout for the given section and then drop another paragraph, button, img etc. on to the content area of that layout. 
The thing is that when ever i drop the first div "layout" and i try to drop an item to that div, it chooses the wrong droppable area, because it is located "behind" the, as if the z-index is wrong, but the correct area is visible.

i made i jsfiddle as an example of the code, I'am logging the id of the droppable area and the dropped item in the console: 
https://jsfiddle.net/g9aragsp/3/

so i would to add one of the "items" to the "insidedrop" instead of the "editor". Ive only set the id "insidedrop" on the first layout for testing purpose.

My html:

```
    <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row content">
        <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
            <div class="row htmlEditor">
                <div class="col-sm-3" style="background-color: gray; min-height: 800px;">
                    <p style="border-bottom: 5px solid black">Layouts</p>

                    <ul id="layouts" style="list-style-type: none;">
                        <li id="layout1" class="PickerButton">layout1</li>
                        <li id="layout2" class="PickerButton">layout2</li>
                        <li id="layout3" class="PickerButton">layout3</li>
                    </ul>

                    <p style="border-bottom: 5px solid black">Items</p>
                    <ul id="items" style="list-style-type: none;">
                        <li id="item1" class="PickerButton">button</li>
                        <li id="item2" class="PickerButton">img</li>
                        <li id="item3" class="PickerButton">text</li>
                    </ul>

                </div>

                <div id="editor" class="col-sm-9" style="background-color: lightgray; min-height: 800px; padding: 20px;">

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My Javascript:
      $(function () {

```
        var $layouts = $("#layouts"),
            $items = $("#items"),
            $insideDrop = $("#insideDrop"),
            $trash = $("#editor");


        $("li", $layouts).draggable({
            cancel: "button", // these elements won't initiate dragging
            revert: "invalid", // when not dropped, the item will revert back to its initial position
            containment: "document",
            helper: "clone",
            cursor: "move"
        });

        $("li", $items).draggable({
            cancel: "button", // these elements won't initiate dragging
            revert: "invalid", // when not dropped, the item will revert back to its initial position
            containment: "document",
            helper: "clone",
            cursor: "move"
        });


        $trash.droppable({
            //accept: "#list1 > li",
            drop: function (event, ui) {
                console.log(ui.draggable.attr("id"));
                console.log($(this).attr("id"));
                if (ui.draggable.attr("id") == "layout1")
                    $("#editor").append("<div class='layout1Outer' style='min-height:400px; margin-bottom: 15px;'><div class='layout1imageplaceholder' style='background-color:#8a2be2;height:150px'></div><div class='layout1content' id='insideDrop' style='background-color:bisque;min-height:250px'></div></div>");

                if (ui.draggable.attr("id") == "layout2")
                    $("#editor").append("<div class='layout2Outer' style='min-height:400px; margin-bottom: 15px;'><div class='layout2imageplaceholder' style='background-color:#8a2be2;float:right;height:400px;width:40%'></div><div class='layout2content' style='background-color:bisque;float:left;min-height:400px;width:60%'></div></div>");

                if (ui.draggable.attr("id") == "layout3")
                    $("#editor").append("<div class='layout3Outer' style='min-height:400px; margin-bottom: 15px;'><div class='layout3imageplaceholder' style='background-color:#8a2be2;float:left;height:400px;width:40%'></div><div class='layout3content' style='background-color:bisque;float:right;min-height:400px;width:60%'></div></div>");


            }
        });

        $insideDrop.droppable({
            drop: function (event, ui) {
                if (ui.draggable.attr("id") == "item1")
                    $("#insideDrop").append("<span id='button' style='background-color:#dc143c;padding: 10px; width: 50px'>BUTTON</span>");

                if (ui.draggable.attr("id") == "item2")
                    $("#insideDrop").append("<img src='http://via.placeholder.com/50x50'>");

                if (ui.draggable.attr("id") == "item3")
                    $("#insideDrop").append("<p style='background- color: #284B63; padding: 10px; width: 200px; color: white;'>Insert text here</p>");


                console.log(ui.draggable.attr("id"));
            }
        });



    });
```

Comment: `$insideDrop` contains no elements. jquery collections are not live.

Comment: so if i understand your comment correct,  i need to initialize it on creating of one of the layouts?

Comment: Yes. though, after doing so it still didn't work. But at least it's a step in the right direction. What's happening now is the editor droppable seems to be taking precedence over the one within the layout.

Comment: Here for example: https://jsfiddle.net/g9aragsp/4/ after disabling the editor droppable on first drop.

Comment: sorry kevin, that dosnt help me at all? this just makes everything "undroppable".

Comment: For me, i'm able to drop a layout, then drop button text and image into the layout.

Comment: did you update the fiddle? i doesnt for me

Comment: Are you dropping into the purple area, or the insideDrop area below it

Comment: yeah it works for me aswell, lol, i dumb.

Comment: only works for layout1 tho

Comment: yeah, thanks, i will look into it and see if i cant find another work around. this kinda defeats the purpose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a solution to the problem. instead of targeting a nested "droppable" container. i reused the same function and on hover made javascript return the current hovered object, and then append the item to that specific object as so:

```
    var hoveredObj;

        function getid(obj) {
            hoveredObj = obj;
    }


        var $layouts = $("#layouts"),
            $items = $("#items"),
            $insideDrop = $("#insideDrop"),
            $editor = $("#editor");


        $("li", $layouts).draggable({
            cancel: "button", // these elements won't initiate dragging
            revert: "invalid", // when not dropped, the item will revert back to its initial position
            containment: "document",
            helper: "clone",
            cursor: "move"
        });

        $("li", $items).draggable({
            cancel: "button", // these elements won't initiate dragging
            revert: "invalid", // when not dropped, the item will revert back to its initial position
            containment: "document",
            helper: "clone",
            cursor: "move"
        });


        $editor.droppable({
            //accept: "#list1 > li",
            drop: function (event, ui) {

                console.log(ui.draggable.attr("id"));
                console.log($(this).attr("id"));
                if (ui.draggable.attr("id") == "layout1")
                    $("#editor").append("<div class='layout1Outer' style='min-height:400px; margin-bottom: 15px;'><div class='layout1imageplaceholder' style='background-color:#8a2be2;height:150px'></div><div class='layout1content' id='insideDrop' onmouseover='getid(this)' style='background-color:bisque;min-height:250px'></div></div>");

                if (ui.draggable.attr("id") == "layout2")
                    $("#editor").append("<div class='layout3Outer' style='min-height:400px; margin-bottom: 15px;'><div class='layout3imageplaceholder' style='background-color:#8a2be2;float:left;height:400px;width:40%'></div><div class='layout3content' style='background-color:bisque;float:right;min-height:400px;width:60%'></div></div>");

                if (ui.draggable.attr("id") == "layout3")
                    $("#editor").append("<div class='layout2Outer' style='min-height:400px; margin-bottom: 15px;'><div class='layout2imageplaceholder' style='background-color:#8a2be2;float:right;height:400px;width:40%'></div><div class='layout2content' style='background-color:bisque;float:left;min-height:400px;width:60%'></div></div>");


                if (ui.draggable.attr("id") == "item1")
                    $(hoveredObj).append("<span id='button' style='background-color:#dc143c;padding: 10px; width: 50px'>BUTTON</span>");

                if (ui.draggable.attr("id") == "item2")
                    $(hoveredObj).append("<img src='http://via.placeholder.com/50x50'>");

                if (ui.draggable.attr("id") == "item3")
                    $(hoveredObj).append("<p style='background- color: #284B63; padding: 10px; width: 200px; color: white;'>Insert text here</p>");

            }
        });
```